# jq to output results as JSON

Tags: json, stream, jq

`jq` is suppose to

> process/filter JSON inputs and producing the filter's results ***as JSON***

However, I found that after the `jq` process/filter, output result is no longer in JSON format any more.

E.g., https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/#result5, i.e.,

```
$ curl -s 'https://api.github.com/repos/stedolan/jq/commits?per_page=5' | jq '.[] | {message: .commit.message, name: .commit.committer.name}'
{
  "message": "Merge pull request #162 from stedolan/utf8-fixes\n\nUtf8 fixes. Closes #161",
  "name": "Stephen Dolan"
}
{
  "message": "Reject all overlong UTF8 sequences.",
  "name": "Stephen Dolan"
}
. . .
```

Is there any workaround?

**UPDATE:**

How to wrap the whole return into a json structure of:

```
{ "Commits": [ {...}, {...}, {...} ] }
```

I've tried:

```
jq '.[] | Commits: [{message: .commit.message, name: .commit.committer.name}]'
jq 'Commits: [.[] | {message: .commit.message, name: .commit.committer.name}]'
```

but neither works.

Comment: This Q/A helped me find a [better Github search approach](https://medium.com/@suntong001/query-github-graphql-9a4547d33bad), FYI.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Technically speaking, unless otherwise instructed (notably with the `-r` command-line option), jq produces a *stream* of JSON entities.

One way to convert an input stream of JSON entities into a JSON array containing them is to use the `-s` command-line option.

### Response to UPDATE

To produce a JSON object of the form:

```
{ "Commits": [ {...}, {...}, {...} ] }
```

you could write something like:

```
jq '{Commits: [.[] | {message: .commit.message, name: .commit.committer.name}]}'
```

(jq understands the '{Commits: _}' shorthand.)

Answer (score 16):

Found it, on the same page,

https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/#result6

> If you want to get the output as a single array, you can tell jq to “collect” all of the answers by wrapping the filter in square brackets:

```
jq '[.[] | {message: .commit.message, name: .commit.committer.name}]'
```

Comment: Those guy are map, why do I want to have a flux of JSON object?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your direct question, if you are doing something like starting with json, then your jq produces a json stream ,

```bash
echo '[{"commit": {"message": "hi"}},{"commit": {"message": "okay"}},{"commit": {"message": "bye"}}]' \
    | jq '.[] | {message: .commit.message}'
```

```bash
{
  "message": "hi"
}
{
  "message": "okay"
}
{
  "message": "bye"
}
```

### Then you just `--slurp` it , like

```bash
echo '[{"commit": {"message": "hi"}},{"commit": {"message": "okay"}},{"commit": {"message": "bye"}}]' \
    | jq '.[] | {message: .commit.message}'\
    | jq --slurp
```

```bash
[
  {
    "message": "hi"
  },
  {
    "message": "okay"
  },
  {
    "message": "bye"
  }
]
```

( NOTE @peak hinted at this , `-s` is short for `--slurp` )